# Registry entry for Visual Studio 2010 Toolbox please ( undoing the slow load fix )

Tags: visual-studio-2010, registry, toolbox

Visual Studio was taking "forever" (over 60 seconds) to open, so I followed advice here to edit the registry:

[Constantly getting "Loading toolbox content from package" in Visual Studio AND IT TAKES FOREVER!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555806/constantly-getting-loading-toolbox-content-from-package-in-visual-studio-and-i)

I found the node in a different location on my machine, however:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Packages{2‌​c298b35-07da-45f1-96a3-be55d91c8d7a}]

I've misplaced the backup file I made of this registry entry, and would like to restore the registry to its original setting. I would be grateful if someone could reply with the contents of that node.

I have Windows 7 x64 BTW.

What I have in this node now is:

```
(Default) .......................REG_SZ..........(value not set)
DefaultItems.....................REG_DWORD.......0x00000001 (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Packages\{2c298b35-07da-45f1-96a3-be55d91c8d7a}]
@="Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage"
"InprocServer32"="C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\mscoree.dll"
"Class"="Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage"
"Assembly"="Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Packages\{2c298b35-07da-45f1-96a3-be55d91c8d7a}\Toolbox]
"Default Items"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my delayed response -- have been away.